# Pipe arguments into bash from terminal

Tags: bash

Let's say I have the script `convertToPNG.sh`

```
convert $1 output.png
```

I can call it via the terminal `$ converToPNG img.jpg`.

But what if instead all I have is the string `"convert $1 output.png"`, and I want to execute it by passing in an argument all in one line?

I don't want to save the string as a file and then run the script with the argument passed in. Isn't there a simpler way to pipe an argument to substitute in the `$1`,

Comment: `eval`? `bash -c`? `bash -s`?

Comment: Do you want to pass filenames to other program? Do you want to run the program with all the arguments all in one `convert img1.jpg img2.jpg outptut.png` or several times one-by-one for each argument? You can use xargs for this, but usage differs depending on your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `eval`. It takes a string and executes it. For example:

```
eval "convert $1 output.png"
```

But take cares, it executes any string, so you should carefully validate your `$1` argument, otherwise anyone may execute any command in your system.

Edit: if what you want is to replace every `$1` by img.gif, try the following (single quopt:

```
bash -c 'convert $1 output.png' 'ignore' 'img.gif'
```

Comment: I have a file `img.gif` that I want to pass in. `eval "convert $1 output.png" img.gif`. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: `convert img.gif output.png`? I am not sure to understand where is your problem here.

Comment: Is there a way to get around replacing every occurrence of `$1` with `img.gif`?

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange use case, but if you really want that you could define your function and pass it the param all in one line:

```
$ myconvert(){ convert "$1" output.png; }; myconvert whatever.gif
```

`whatever.gif` being the file you want to convert.